# Handling multiple resource layouts using one java class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-4.1

Is it possible to handle two or more resource layouts using one java class in android development? I want to create a multi-page signup page with one java class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Solution: **Use Fragment under a Frame Layout in your main class**.

Alter Solution: **Use View Visibility GONE/VISIBLE to Load many views in one activity**

Alter Solution: **You Can Load Previous View data locally and load new content view by simply calling setContentView(R.layout."new layout");**